# Choropleth Map with state level US Voter Data (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, choropleth

I am working on a project about voting patterns in the US and I have some state-level data which I am having some trouble turning into a choropleth map.

I did some research and found ff.create_choropleth in the plotly figure factory library, however, from what I can understand in the notation, it requires county-level FIP data. I only have FIPS data for State-level analysis (1-56, up to Wyoming). How can I go around this?

edit: I have the data for previous elections, what I was trying to ask was how to use Python to create a choropleth map, given that I have ONLY state FIP and not county FIP.

Sorry for the amateurish question, this is my first Python project!

edit2: I'm using https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.figure_factory.create_choropleth.html and here are some examples of the data I'm working with (I cut it out from a larger table with more variables other than "voted", it's actually quite simple data (don't want to make this question too long).[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the current US election.  I'm not certain where/if that data is available publicly.  I know that there is a proprietary data feed from the Associated Press that is very pricey, you'd have to reach out to them to get it.

Alternatively, you could try to scrape a public source that is reporting results (such as Politico or another site) but then its still a question of your data granularity.  I don't believe they report at the FIPS level.

I guess the short answer to your question is: "You have to buy it, to the best of my knowledge."

EDIT:

Ok, if you're going based off of this (https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/) then if you only have the state FIPS code, I'd try looking up all the county fips and basically just applying the data across all counties:

State FIPS: https://www.nrcs.usda.gov/wps/portal/nrcs/detail/?cid=nrcs143_013696

County FIPS: https://www.nrcs.usda.gov/wps/portal/nrcs/detail/national/home/?cid=nrcs143_013697

If you make a final datasource with all of the county fips set to the value of the state FIPS, maybe it'll all show up the same color?

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I have the data for previous elections, what I was trying to ask was how to use Python to create a choropleth map, given that I have ONLY state FIP and not county FIP. I'm an international student, so if there's a way to convert STATE FIP to county FIP format that applies for the entire State, that would be super helpful!!

Comment: OH!  FIP breaks down to county level, if you have state associated, the easiest I would think of is to aggregate by that.  Sorry I didn't address the question.  I'll remove the answer shortly

Comment: Oh I see, how would I go about aggregating by it? Sorry I'm so full of questions :(

Comment: @Kei222, can you provide an example of the form of the data that you're getting and how you're generating the choropleth map?  I'm not sure what libraries/techniques you're using.  I've only had a bit of experience with the data you were referring to.

Comment: @Kei222, without having anything more granular, there isn't much you can do, unless you apply that value to all the counties uniformly as mentioned.  The tutorial thats linked in the answer also has the underlying country FIPS data, so not sure if that will help you though.